# Why asp.net textbox isnt storing state over postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Ive got some textboxes on a page and they are declared like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbVerbalyAgreed" ViewStateMode="Enabled" CssClass="datepickerTarget" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

But when I post the page back the contents are clearing out which is annoying because I have cleary set the ViewState to on. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Your markup is fine. You must have another setting or code somewhere where you are resetting its value.

Comment: Can you show us you `Page_Load` code please?

Comment: Do you set `ReadOnly` property value to `true` on this textbox in code?

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` from the inputs and let them use the default settings.

I would also check to make sure that ViewState is enabled in the `web.config`, and make sure that you don't have any containers (Panel, PlaceHolder, etc.) around the controls with `EnableViewState` set to false.  - thanks @Uwe Keim

Comment: And that it is not disabled by a parent element in the control hierarchy (e.g. the page itself).